# Finite $k$th moment of a function of random variable

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, moments

Let $X = a/h$, where $X$, $a$ and $h$ are random variables, with $X$ an i.i.d. sequence.

If $X$ has finite 8th moment, can we infer that $a$ has finite $8$th moment as well? Thanks

Comment: What kinds of mathematical objects are $a_n$ and $h_n$? Is one of them an ordinary sequence of numbers or are they both sequences of random variables?  If the latter, are each $(a_n,h_n)$ independent or not?

Comment: I should be more precise, the objects $X_n$, $a_n$ and $h_n$ are random variables, with $X_n$ an iid sequence and $h_n$ measurable wrt $n-1$ information set.

Comment: Please specify that in your question.  Because the question is really about each *individual* $X_n,$ it would be clearer to drop the subscripts altogether.

Comment: Just did as per your comments, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @ChristophHanck's good example (+1), let $a_n=h_n$ be any RV with $k$-th moment undefined. The ratio $a_n/h_n$ is $1$, which is constant but still a RV, with a finite $k$-th moment.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $h=1/Y$, where $Y\sim N(0,1)$, too. Then, $a=hX=X/Y$, which is Cauchy.